# Korach, Chukas, Balak - The mouth of the earth, well & donkey

Tags: sources-mekorot, pirke-avot-ethicsof, parashat-balak, chukas, parshat-korach

I noticed something this week when reciting Pirkei Avos...

[In Perek 5, Mishna 6](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.5.6?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) - the mishna famously says:

> עֲשָׂרָה דְבָרִים נִבְרְאוּ בְּעֶרֶב שַׁבָּת בֵּין הַשְּׁמָשׁוֹת, וְאֵלּוּ הֵן, **פִּי הָאָרֶץ, וּפִי הַבְּאֵר, וּפִי הָאָתוֹן**, וְהַקֶּשֶׁת, וְהַמָּן, וְהַמַּטֶּה, וְהַשָּׁמִיר, וְהַכְּתָב, וְהַמִּכְתָּב, וְהַלּוּחוֹת. וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים, אַף הַמַּזִּיקִין, וּקְבוּרָתוֹ שֶׁל משֶׁה, וְאֵילוֹ שֶׁל אַבְרָהָם אָבִינוּ. וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים, אַף צְבָת בִּצְבָת עֲשׂוּיָה
>
> Ten things were created on the eve of the Sabbath at twilight, and these are they: **(1) the mouth of the earth, (2) the mouth of the well, (3) the mouth of the donkey**, (4) the rainbow, (5) the manna, (6) the staff [of Moses], (7) the shamir, (8) the letters, (9) the writing, (10) and the tablets. And some say: also the demons, the grave of Moses, and the ram of Abraham, our father. And some say: and also tongs, made with tongs.

I found it interesting that the first three each appear in consecutive parshios. The mouth of the earth is obviously Parshas Korach, the mouth of the well receives attention in Chukas as due to Miriam's death it dried up (refer to [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.20.2?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Numbers.20.2.1&lang2=bi) there on Bamidbar 20:2) and the mouth of the donkey is in Parshas Balak.

Do any sources make this observation? And if so, what might the reason be?

Comment: Chronological order?

Comment: Thanks @MauriceMizrahi - but it is only chronological as far as these three. The rainbow makes an appearance in parshas Noach, the ram in parshas vayeira etc.

Comment: those 3 form a subset of mouth related miracles, so it makes sense to list them in an internal chronological order.

Comment: @Menachem that's a nice idea! Does anyone say this or is it your own ha'arah?

Comment: @Dov just my thought

Comment: Was at a Chabad shiur and the rabbi actually gave a whole class about this and mentioned the successive order of the 3, so other people know this too apparently