Relationship Korach, Chukat and Balak, 3 mouths
What is the relationship or connection, if any, between the following aspect of the three parashiyot Korach, Chukat, and Balak. Each parasha mentions one of three "mouths": the mouth of the earth (Korach), the mouth of the well (Chukat), and the mouth of Balaam's donkey (Balak)?

Hasn't this been asked before?

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/130029/korach-chukas-balak-the-mouth-of-the-earth-well-donkey

Good catch that they appear in 3 consecutive parshiot. They are all among the special exceptions to nature God created just before the end of the sixth day.
Pirkei avot:
Ten things were created on the eve of the Sabbath at twilight, and these are they: [1] the mouth of the earth, [2] the mouth of the well, [3] the mouth of the donkey, [4] the rainbow, [5] the manna, [6] the staff [of Moses], [7] the shamir, [8] the letters, [9] the writing, [10] and the tablets. And some say: also the demons, the grave of Moses, and the ram of Abraham, our father. And some say: and also tongs, made with tongs

This doesn't answer the question it merely backs it up.

It does. It adds the facts that they were special last minute creations.

What relationship does that fact have with Korach, Chukat and Balak?

You're correct, but there must be a reason why these three "mouths" appear in three consecutive parashiyot, even though these parashiyot are not in chronological order. This suggests that Hashem intentionally arranged them this way, and there must be a reason for it.

Where does it mention the "mouth of the well" exactly?

@MichoelR Tos. Yom Tov explains עלי באר ענו־לה (Chukat 21:17) means the well spoke and they answered. Hence it had a "mouth"

@MichoelR - a few weeks ago I was wondering whether the missing overt mention of פי הבאר might have been due to Moshe hitting the rock - and if he had merely spoken to the rock, it would have highlighted the neis better for קידוש השם and might have had an overt mention in the wording for פי הבאר and might have had something similar to the other two such as: ויפתח ה' את פי הבאר

Why are you assuming these parashiyot to not be in chronological order?

Perhaps the additional reason is the functionality of the mouths. After the sin of the spies it appeared that Hashem cut all communication with the Jewish people. The placement of the mouths is a hint that He did not. The mouth of the Earth - punishes the wicked. The mouth of the well - provides for the righteous in this world. The mouth of a donkey - communicates with everyone and more so with Jewish people. Talmud Megilla 31a, Rabbi Yoḥanan said: Wherever you find a reference in the Bible to the might of the Holy One, Blessed be He, you also find a reference to His humility adjacent to it. Mouth of a donkey - that was a level at which Bil'am could learn his lesson.
